# Java XML Document converting &quot; to "(literal quote) upon parsing/converting to Document

Tags: java, xml

I have this problem where I need to send to soap webservice that requires the root tag to have an xml data, this the xml that I'm trying to send:

```
<root>&lt;test key=&quot;Applicants&quot;&gt;this is a data&lt;/test&gt;</root>
```

I need to append this to the SoapBody object as a document with this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false); 

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document result = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getRequest().getBytes()));
```

Then adding it to the SoapBody to be sent to the webservice.

However, upon sending this request and tracing the logs, it's actually reverting the &quot; character to literal quotes (")

This is the xml being sent:

```
<root>&lt;test key="Applicants"&gt;this is a data&lt;/test&gt;</root>
```

As you can see, the " is being transformed to literal quotes, how can I keep the original data within root tag (which has the &quot;)? It seems to be transforming it when I'm converting it to a Document object.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Edit:

The webservice actually requires this format (from their documentation and sample xml requests), if this isn't possible, is it a limitation? Should I user another framework?

Comment: Quotes only have to be escaped when in an attribute value. As text between tags, they don't need escaping, so that result is perfectly valid XML. There is nothing to fix, because there is nothing wrong.

Comment: What will I do if it's the requirement of the webservice, it should be transformed to &quot; (as written on their documentation and sample xml requests)? Is this a limitation? thanks.

Comment: All XML parsers will parse `&quot;` and `"` exactly the same way. It is common to use a unified XML encoder for both attributes and text, so they escape `"` as `&quot;`, but that is just convenience. Text between tags don't *need* that escaping, but it's ok to do it. Ignore the issue, it'll work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"` and `&quot;` are completely equivalent in this context. You haven't actually said whether this is causing a problem: if it is, then it's because some recipient of the XML isn't processing it correctly. Incidentally, it would also be legitimate to convert the `&gt;` to `>`.

When you parse XML and re-serialise it, irrelevant details like redundant whitespace get lost - just as if you copy this text into your text editor, the line-wrapping and font size gets lost.